# Loop Cut Factor doesn't work from -.85/.85 further

Tags: loop

I don't understand why the Factor doesn't allow me to bring the loop cut closer to an edge. It's all good up to -.85/.85 and from there it snaps the cut to the other edge. I can't get the cut closer than 10mm distance from another edge. How can I adjust the Factor to hold the cut up to the last mm, in other words to go -1/1 the way is supposed to?

Here is a video with what's going on when I apply a loop cut to an object. [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X-6vvYVEFiQg_K-iEekr3tXTRN47Lz73/view?usp=sharing) I have no idea why the loop cut doesn't hold or why the Factor doesn't let me go further than .85 on one side and -.84 on the other side. Please let me know if you have a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I having trouble trying to reproduce this, could you illustrate the circumstances to give more context?

Comment: I cannot replicate this either - seems to work fine. Maybe share a file.